# Sensor List in Samsung GT-I9300

Tags: android, android-sensors

Please help.I am trying to get all the available sensors of a android device.But when i tried to get from  'GT_19300' it shows a list given below

```
      "LSM330DLC 3-axis Accelerometer
      AK8975C 3-axis Magnetic field sensor
      iNemoEngine Orientation sensor
      CM36651 Light sensor
      CM36651 Proximity sensor
      LSM330DLC Gyroscope sensor
      iNemoEngine Gravity sensor
      iNemoEngine Linear Acceleration sensor
      iNemoEngine Rotation_Vector sensor
      LPS331AP Pressure Sensor
      Rotation Vector Sensor
      Gravity Sensor
      Linear Acceleration Sensor
      Orientation Sensor
      Corrected Gyroscope Sensor"
```

I am feeling that the list has some repeat names. I want to know that is this all sensors  available in GT_19300 or is it a repetition.If i am using the Gyroscope Sensor which one i want to use. Please share your valid answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

'iNemoEngine xxx' should be a kind of 'virtual sensor', like 'rotation_vector sensor' implemented in ICS by Google.

Accelerometer,
Magnetic,
Light,
Proximity,
Gyroscope, 
Pressure, 
Gravity, 
**these are hardware-sensor.**

others like 
linear accerlerometer, 
rotation vector, 
orientation, 
**these are software implemented using sensor fusion algorithm.**

you dont need to care about these names but try:

```
public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
    switch(event.sensor.getType()) {

             case Sensor.TYPE_GYROSCOPE:
             // 
             // your processing
             break;
            }
     }
```

for gyroscope on S3, I believe you will receive data from 'LSM330DLC Gyroscope sensor'.

hope this will help.

Comment: Thank you and I want a conformation from any one. Once again thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if it helps, but you can install an app called "Elixir" which lists the sensors on the device. You can search for it on the Play Store.

Comment: I think "Elixir" have some default sensor list and showing is it available or not. I really mean to get all the sensors with out per-define.i did it but in the case of GT_19300 only i am getting this problem

Comment: try the app "Android info" to know sensors avialable