# Power Usage of (virtual) Sensors Android

Tags: android, sensors, android-sensors, sensor-fusion

Looking through the capabilities of my Nexus 4 I noticed that Sensors seem to be reported multiple times.

I haven't worked with sensors (or Smartphones in general) before, so I used some apps to get an overview: the Device Analyzer from [AndroidFragmentation.com](http://www.androidfragmentation.com) and the [Sensors Explorer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.salvo.sensorsexplorer) both bring up 15 sensors. You can see the results [here](http://www.androidfragmentation.com/database/v/dr/622951/oem/LGE/dm/Nexus%204/carrier/Telco).

And while according to [iFixIt.com](http://www.ifixit.com/Teardown/Nexus+4+Teardown/11781/3) there is an [Invensense MPU-6050](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.salvo.sensorsexplorer) built in as (only) Gyroscope and Accelerometer, Android reports:

- 2 Sensors by LGE

  - "LGE Accelerometer Sensor"
  - "LGE Gyroscope Sensor"
- 2 by Qualcomm

  - "Linear Acceleration"
  - "Rotation Vector"
- 4 by Google

  - "Rotation Vector Sensor"
  - "Linear Acceleration Sensor"
  - "Orientation Sensor"
  - "Corrected Gyroscope Sensor"

According to [Sensor List in Samsung GT-I9300](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14228852/sensor-list-in-samsung-gt-i9300) some of those sensors will be "virtual". However, what is actually interesting to me at the moment is the power consumtion of the sensors. And that is the point where I get really confused.

Take the accelerometer as an example: "LGE Accelerometer Sensor" reports 0.5 mA, whereas the "Linear Acceleration" (Qualcomm) reports 4.1 mA and "Linear Acceleration Sensor" (Google) reports 9.1 mA. All three have the same Resolution (0.0011901855 SU), LGE and Qualcomm have the same maximum range (39.226593 SU), while Google reports 19.6133 SU.

I first thought this may give access to different operation modes, which would explain the differing values, but then again, why would this explain other vendors.

Now: How many Accelerators are actually present? Are they really redundant, or are they just virtual access paths to the same device? If so, why does the power usage differ so vastly? And why the range?

**Update**
According to the Specifications the Gyroscope will drain a current of 3.6mA (matching "LGE Gyroscope Sensor", all other report 9.1mA) and the Accelerometer might vary between 500µA in normal operation Mode and 10µA @ 1.25Hz to 110µA @ 40Hz in low power mode.

With a voltage of 3V (typical according to Specs) this yields 10.8mW for the Gyroscope and 10µW to 1,5mW for the Accelerometer.

The sensors which report "Google Inc." seem to be virtual ones, which perform sensor-fusion to deliver values of higher accuracy and usability. See [this Google Tech Talk](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=C7JQ7Rpwn2k).

Answer (score 1):

Usually there is only one physical acceleration sensor present on the device.

This signal can then be divided to linear acceleration and gravitation. It can be achieved by a low-pass filter like the [android documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/SensorEvent.html#values) states. The result can then be improved by the gyroscope and the magnetometer. This is frequently done on software side - so linear acceleration, orientation and gravity power consumption is usually the sum of the accelerometer's, gyroscope's and probably also the magnetometer's consumption value.

Apparently the qualcomm linear acceleration sensor uses the accelerometer and the gyroscope to calculate the value, while google's version also considers the magnetometer.

The resolution is bound to the physical sensor. For the range I can't say for sure, but probably it has something to do with the relation:

> Acceleration = Linear Acceleration + Gravity

Physical sensors:

- Accelerometer
- Gyroscope
- Magnetometer

Sensor Fusion:

- Linear Accleration
- Gravity
- Orientation/Rotation
- Corrected Gyroscope

However you can't say for sure if a sensor is physically present or just a product of sensor fusion.